# Is the expected payoff function of a diffusion process of the class of $C^1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, greens-function

Let $X_t$ be a diffusion process taking values on interval $[l,r]$, and satisfies SDE $dX_t = \mu(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)^2/2dB_t$ with $\sigma(\cdot)$ bounded away from 0, and $\mu,\sigma$ bounded.
Let $$u(x) = E\left[\left.\int_0^\tau e^{-rt}g(X_t)dt\right|X_0=x\right]$$ be the expected cumulatieve discounted payoff starting from $x$, where $\tau$ is the first exit time from $(a,b)$ for some $l<a<x<b<r$ and $g$ is bounded and measurable.

I want to show that $u\in C^1$.

This is relative easy when $\mu,\sigma$ are Lipschitz continuous. In that case one can write
$$u(x) = \int_a^b g(y) G_r(x,y)dy$$
and where $G_r(x,y)$ is the Green function for some boundary value problem of a 2nd-order ODE.
The green function can be written as (see Page 19, Handbook of Brownian Motion – Facts
and Formulae, 2nd Edition, Borodin and Salminen).
$$
G_r(x,y) =\begin{cases} w_r^{-1}\psi_r(x)\phi_r(y), & x\leq y \\
w_r^{-1}\psi_r(y)\phi_r(x), & x\geq y\end{cases}
$$
where $\psi_r,\phi_r$ are the fundamental solutions of ODE
$$
\sigma(x)^2/2 v''(x) +\mu(x)v'(x)=r v(x).
$$
If $\sigma$ and $\mu$ are Lipschitz continuous, then $\psi_r,\phi_r\in C^2$,
and the rest of showing $u(x)\in C^1$ is simple (actually in this case one can show $u(x)\in C^2$, see Page 226 of Stochastic calculus: a practical introduction - ‎Durrett).

However in my application $\sigma$ and $\mu$ are **piece-wise** Lipchitz continuous (let's say has exactly one jump discontinuity point in $(a,b)$).

One way to proceed is to argue that $\psi_r,\phi_r\in C^1$, which is quite obvious in my perspective.
Are there any result in the literature stating this fact even if $\sigma$ and $\mu$ is not Lipschitz?

Or does any literature discuss the condition for the smoothness of the cumulated discounted payoff function $u(\cdot)$?

Comment: From what I recall, Lipschitz continuity is usually needed to ensure the existence and uniqueness of a solution to that SDE.  Are you sure you still get a unique solution if you only have piecewise Lipschitz continuity?

Comment: @user6247850 In my application $\mu(\cdot)/\sigma^2(\cdot)$ is constant (they are discontinuous at the same point). So one solution is time-changed BM with drift. I forget about the argument for uniqueness, for now, but I remember it was covered in some textbook exercise.

Comment: @user6247850 See page 396 
Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus, Karatzas and Shreve, Second Edition.